# NGINX Configuration to send traffic to Server over HTTPS and NGINX being client

Tags: nginx, proxy, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a backend docker container that will be connecting to external Server and in between these two there is a NGINX Server. Connection from the Docker container to NGINX is over HTTP and from NGINX to the Server is over HTTPS.

We have the client.crt and client.key file certified by the server to connect. when we use that directly as below it works.

```
# curl -i -X POST -d @event.json --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://localhost:8443/eventListener/v7 -k --cert client.crt --key client.key
HTTP/1.1 100

HTTP/1.1 202
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 8
Date: Sat, 16 May 2020 15:41:12 GMT

Accepted
#
```

Now I want from the docker container which is behind the NGINX can connect to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the configuration.

```
worker_processes 1;
events { worker_connections 1024; }
http {
     sendfile on;

     server {
          listen 1111;
          server_name 10.211.2.231;

          location / {
               proxy_pass https://10.211.2.231:8223$request_uri;
               proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/client.crt;
               proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/client.key;
               proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
          }
     }
}
```